# 3D quiver arrow look

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I´m trying to plot an arrow inside a sphere and have the following code

```
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)
fig = pl.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0,blocx[0], blocy[0], blocz[0],color="b",linewidth=5)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color ='#15B05E')

ax.view_init(30, 70)
pl.show()
```

where the blocx, y and z are some data I have. As a result, I get this:
[image]

but I´d like the arrow head to be like a cone, as well as smaller in size, how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you want the arrowhead to be a cone shape? I don't think quiver could do that. You might have to make a cone surface from scratch to get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

##### Scroll to the bottom to see an edit with a more complete answer!

[`quiver`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) does not have this feature. One way to solve that issue is by making a function which plots arrows for you. Within this function you can customize the format of the arrows.

Here is the output from my **original code**. It will **only plot an arrow along the z-axis** but the apex can be a positive or negative value of any magnitude. One could easily make changes for the arrow to fall along a different axis, but giving it an arbitrary direction becomes much more complicated (see the edit below for an explanation of how to do this).

[image: Arrow w/ cone for head]

Note: Using `fig.gca()` will give you the following deprecation warning. To avoid this, you should call `ax=plt.subplot(projection='3d')`.

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Calling gca() with keyword arguments was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.4. Starting two minor releases later, gca() will take no keyword arguments. The gca() function should only be used to get the current axes, or if no axes exist, create new axes with default keyword arguments. To create a new axes with non-default arguments, use plt.axes() or plt.subplot().
> ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#### Original Code

(Keep scrolling for details on parameters)

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_arrow(axe=None,
              apex=None, col='b', tipHeight=None, tipWidth=None, heightRatio=.25, widthRatio=0.1,
              **plt_kwargs):
    
    def f(x, y, height):
        return np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2) *-1.0 *height
        
    if (ax is not None) and (apex is not None):
        if tipHeight is None:
            tipHeight = np.sqrt(apex * 1.0) *heightRatio *apex /abs(apex);
        if tipWidth is None:
            tipWidth = np.sqrt(apex * 1.0) *widthRatio;
        u1, v1 = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:100j, 0:np.pi:80j]
        x1 = np.cos(u1)*np.sin(v1)
        y1 = np.sin(u1)*np.sin(v1)
        z1 = f(x1, y1, tipHeight) + apex
        axe.plot_surface(x1 *tipWidth, y1 *tipWidth, z1, color=col, **plt_kwargs)
        axe.plot3D((0,0),(0,0),(0,apex-(tipHeight)),c=col,linewidth=3, **plt_kwargs)
    return(ax) 
            
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j]
x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)

zApexVal = 1

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))

ax = plt.subplot(111,projection='3d')
ax.view_init(30, 70)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color ='#15B05E')
add_arrow(ax, zApexVal)

plt.show()
```

The parameters which need to be passed for the arrow to be generated are `axe` (the axis) and `apex` which is a value along the z-axis which specifies the end of the arrow. The `col` parameter controls the color of the arrow and defaults to blue. Additionally, one can specify the height/width of the arrowhead. This can also be controlled by assigning a ratio to each value. The ratios are applied to the size of the arrow and scale the head accordingly.

## Edit

In the first part of this answer, I provided a code snippet that only plots arrows along the z-axis. This is helpful in some cases, but it does not fully solve the problem. Using the code below it is possible to plot a 3D arrow with a conical head pointing in any direction! Here is an example animation that demonstrates the arrow pointing in different directions...

[image: Rotating 3D arrow animation]

#### Mathematical Explanation

Before orienting the arrow to point in a given direction, we must first create the set of data points that describe the conical head and cylindrical tail. It is easy enough to create a meshgrid of points near the origin that can be used to plot the surface of the cone. The equations for this construction are:

> x = cos(θ)sin(φ)
>
> y = sin(θ)sin(φ)
>
> z = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)

After the data is created, one can perform vector operations to translate and rotate the cone. We use the [scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.html) class from SciPy v1.11.4 to create rotation objects from a tuple of angles. Each angle in the tuple represents a rotation about the x-, y-, or z-axis. These objects can be represented in matrix form. To rotate the cone data, one should take the dot product of the data set and the rotation matrix. The result is the data that can be plotted as a surface for the head of the arrow! See [Rotation.from_euler(...)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.from_euler.html) for more information on the rotation object used in this example.

#### Edited Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

# rotAngles is a tuple of rotation angles about each axis in degrees 
def define_arrow(apex=None, start=[0,0,0], rotAngles=(0,45,0), length=1.0, tipHeight=None,
                 tipWidth=None, heightRatio=0.5, widthRatio=0.25):
    # creating the Rotation object
    r = R.from_euler('xyz', rotAngles, degrees=True)
    def f(x, y, height):
        return np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2) *-1.0*height
    
    if apex is not None:
        if tipHeight is None:
            tipHeight = np.sqrt(apex * 1.0) *heightRatio *apex /abs(apex);
        if tipWidth is None:
            tipWidth = np.sqrt(apex * 1.0) *widthRatio;
        u1, v1 = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:100j, 0:np.pi:100j]
        x1 = np.cos(u1)*np.sin(v1)
        y1 = np.sin(u1)*np.sin(v1)
        z1 = f(x1, y1, tipHeight) + apex
        
        x1 *= tipWidth
        y1 *= tipWidth
        # applying rotations
        vals = np.dot(np.dstack((x1,y1,z1)),r.as_matrix().T)
        vals2 = np.dot(np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1]]),r.as_matrix().T)
    
    return vals,vals2 # vals is cone data, vals2 is tail data
    
# setting up the figure and axes objects
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)
ax.set_aspect('equal') # THIS IS IMPORTANT!! W/O THIS LINE, THE ARROW IS LOPSIDED
ax.view_init(15, 90)

# creating data for the wireframe sphere
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:12j, 0:np.pi:18j]
x = np.cos(u)*np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u)*np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)

zApexVal = 1 # distance from the origin to the tip of the arrow

covals,rovals = define_arrow(zApexVal) # creating data for cone and tail

ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color ='#15B05E', alpha=0.8, zorder=1) # plotting the green sphere
ax.plot_surface(covals[:,:,0], covals[:,:,1], covals[:,:,2], color='b', zorder=3) # plot the arrow head
ax.plot3D(rovals[:,0] *.9,rovals[:,1] *.9,rovals[:,2] *.9, color='b', zorder=2) # plot the arrow tail

plt.show()
```